# Using WCF netTcpBinding with Android Client

Tags: android, wcf, tcpclient, nettcpbinding

I currently have a windows based client, implemented with Silverlight that uses a bidirectional tcp connection with the server using WCF Net.tcp (netTcpBinding).

Now I would like to develop an Android based client with minimum changes on the server side.

1. Is it possible to use netTcpBinding with Android client?
2. What would be the best way to do that?
3. If not, are there recommended ways to achieve a secure bidirectional connection with the server other than the standard tcp socket connection?

I saw the following solution [How to Consume WCF Service with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android)
But it offeres basicHttpBinding. Any idea how can i make the Android client to connect and how can i get calls from the server?

Comment: What's wrong with using BasicHttpBinding? It's interoperable.

Answer (score 2):

`NetTcpBinding` stars with NET prefix which means .NET only. It is not interoperable binding. The only way to make it work means implementing [underlaying protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336626/cant-get-nettcpbinding-requests-to-show-up-in-fiddler/6336685#6336685) on client side by yourselves. I'm almost sure that it doesn't worth it (unless you going to sell that implementation).

Security with `NetTcpBinding` is achieved either by windows domain or by certificates.

If you want bidirectional secure communication with Android device I expect you will have to use different technology instead of WCF or use another (non-MS) transport channel.